# Android - how to export eclipse project with libraries to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

my tries 
click right at my project , choose Export ---> android
---> Generate Gradle build files

[image]

I stop in this point , I cant force overriding, any one know the reason

[image]

Comment: Have you read http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html ?

Comment: site not available but I read every article about exporting eclipse project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse IDE uses a different file structure for their android projects, as opposed to the files structure of the projects created through Android Studio. Regardless of the Gradle builds and so on.

Your best bet would be to create a new Android Project based on the specifications of your Eclipse project. And migrate the source code as required. As far as the libraries are concerned, you can add them directly to the Android Project.

I also found that this might be useful for your current situation. [Help on Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio (Projects).](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Hope this helps.